# How to export React class component with proper type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've problem with exporting React class component and use it in Enzyme, because it's exporting as function type:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
...
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
export const MyComponentRaw = MyComponent
```

and next, when I'm trying to use it in Enzyme:

```js
import {MyComponentRaw} from "../../MyComponent";

const wrapper = shallow<typeof MyComponentRaw>(<MyComponentRaw />)
```

it's is visible as `function`.

On the other hand, when I exported component directly:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {
...
}
```

I'm able to use it in Enzyme:

```
import MyComponentRaw from "../../MyComponent";

const wrapper = shallow<typeof MyComponentRaw>(<MyComponentRaw />)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export the class component and the default with the connect.

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

You can import the unconnected component in the tests like

```
import {MyComponent} from '/the/location';
```

And you can import the connected component using

```
import ConnectedMyComponent from '/the/location';
```

Comment: It works. I didn't know, that I can export in this way (I'm new in JS/TS). Thank You very much for Your help